# Clear TextField rather than append

Tags: geb

I'm using the following statement to clear text filed value:

```
input.value("abc")
input.value("")
input.value("def")
```

But, instead of clearing and set new value, it is appending the new value to old value. ('abcdef').

Is there any way to clear the TextField, before setting new val?

Answer (score 2):

You can clear using the selenium element:

```
input.firstElement().clear()
```

And you can send keys using << like so:

```
input << "abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selenium Keys to backspace the texts that you already had entered. You can try many different ways to accomplish that. Here is a simple way to do that:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys

input.value("abc")
input.value(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "A")+Keys.BACK_SPACE)
input.value("def")
```

It should do the job. Let us know whether it worked for you or not!

Cheers@!