# How to clear the field of web element - Groovy

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy, geb

According to chapter 4.10 of this [documentation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.10.0/navigator.html):

To clear the field of webElement I can do:

```
webElement << Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.BACK_SPACE)
```

But it doesn't look clean for me.
Is there a way to write a method named "clear" which could be called on a webElement and invokation of this method would look like this?

```
webElement.clear()
```

How this method would look then?

I managed just to do something like this:

```
def clear() {
    return Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.BACK_SPACE)
}

webElement << clear()
```

Do I have other possibilities or approaches to this problem to be able to call a method on element to clear it?

I can not use the selenium method clear() cause the spark framework which supports application which I test forbid this method.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this solution doesn't work for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946779/clear-textfield-rather-than-append

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear TextField rather than append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946779/clear-textfield-rather-than-append)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to clear an element in Geb is to simply set it’s value to an empty string:

```
$(“input”).value(“”)
```

That will call WebElement’s `clear()` method so if that’s not an option and you would actually want to perform the key press combination as in your question then you have two options. My preferred one would be to write a module with a `clear()` method:

```
class ManuallyCleared extends Module {
    void clear() {
         leftShift Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, “a”, Keys.SPACE)
    }
}
```

And the use it like:

```
$(“input”).module(ManuallyCleared).clear()
```

Another option would be to implement a [custom navigator](http://gebish.org/manual/current/#navigator-factory) and add the `clear()` method there.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to pass the driver you're using so you don't have to use keypresses. You can use .Clear() to clear any text in a textbox.

```
def Clear(driver):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("elementName")
    elem.clear()
```

or

```
def Clear(driver):
    driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByName('schedule')[0].value = ''')
```

Comment: You don't want to use JS unless it's absolutely necessary. When you do this, you are doing things a user can't do so you are no longer testing user scenarios but you also are going around any validations, etc. that the page/field is doing. The best approach is to interact with the page as a user would.

Comment: This is true, I used the JS method above for only entering a date in a field that used a JS date selection window to populate. It is risky but i do come across a need to use it from time to time. Just another alternative.

Answer (score -1):

One option you could try is to extend or overwrite the WebElement class and then add in your own `clear()` method that can be called on the webDriver element.

so then you could just say `webElement.clear()` instead of `webElement << clear()`